# Lua code statistics program/plugin

Tags: linux, software-development, lua

When programming in C++, I have a Code::Blocks plugin that tells me statistics about a project (not just one file), like code to comment percentages, lines of code in project etc.

Screenshot from Code::Blocks:

[image: Code::Blocks code statistics plugin]

I was wondering whether there was a similar program/plugin for Lua, so I can view statistics of all my code in a certain directory. (I'm using an IDE called ZeroBrane Studio, if anyone knows a plugin for that)

I'm running Ubuntu (Linux) 14.04 and it doesn't need to be compatible with Windows or Mac because Lua isn't a compiled language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/):

- free, open source, CLI
- support many languages including Lua

Example:

```
prompt> cloc perl-5.10.0.tar.gz
    4076 text files.
    3883 unique files.                                          
    1521 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.50  T=12.0 s (209.2 files/s, 70472.1 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Perl                          2052         110356         130018         292281
C                              135          18718          22862         140483
C/C++ Header                   147           7650          12093          44042
Bourne Shell                   116           3402           5789          36882
Lisp                             1            684           2242           7515
make                             7            498            473           2044
C++                             10            312            277           2000
XML                             26            231              0           1972
yacc                             2            128             97           1549
YAML                             2              2              0            489
DOS Batch                       11             85             50            322
HTML                             1             19              2             98
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                          2510         142085         173903         529677
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```